# Is the étale site a small category?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, set-theory, schemes

Consider the étale site $X_{ét}$ of a scheme $X$. As a category, this is the collection of all étale schemes over $X$.

Now, is this a set (i.e., is the étale site a small category)? If $X=Spec\ k$, one could suspect that every set has a scheme structure which is étale over $X$. Namely, $\coprod Spec \ k$, where the coproduct is taken over the cardinality of the set. If so, the class of étale schemes over $X$ would be a proper class.

Is this true?

Thank you in advance.

P.S.: My question is motivated by the following: if $X_{ét}$ is a proper class, I'm afraid $Sets^{X_{ét}^{op}}$ shouldn't be a category. But the theory of étale cohomology and of the étale topos is based on the fact that its "subcategory" of sheaves on the étale site $Sh(X_{ét})$ is indeed a category (which we call the étale topos). So, either $Sh(X_{ét})$ while $Sets^{X_{ét}^{op}}$ is not, which would be strange to me, or we have a problem.

Comment: The étale site is small, because of the "locally of finite presentation" condition. An étale map is analogous to a finite covering space in topology.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Do you mean "*locally* small?" Unless I'm missing something, every isomorphism type of a scheme is represented by proper-class-many specific set-theoretic objects (analogously to how the category of finite groups is not small), so it shouldn't be small.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I mean “essentially small”, i.e. equivalent to a small category. Sorry to be imprecise, it’s just that literal smallness isn’t the significant concept.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Oh I agree, but the OP is asking about smallness per se.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I assumed the issue was about whether presheaves on the étale site are a (locally small) category, which is equivalent to the site being essentially small, since that's the issue with actual mathematical consequences. But maybe that wasn't the point.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: It's not essentially small, though, because its objects are only _locally_ of finite presentation.  As mentioned in the question, you can take an arbitrarily large disjoint union of etale maps to get another one.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, duh. Thanks. I had somehow a burning belief that the site should be small, probably because people worry about the much worse non-smallness of the pro-etale site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right: $X_{ét}$ is large (in fact, essentially large).  This means that there is no category of presheaves on $X_{ét}$ in ZFC, or if you are using universes you would need to go to a higher universe to talk about the category of presheaves.

However, the category of *sheaves* $Sh(X_{ét})$ is indeed a genuine category that can be defined without enlarging your universe.  This is because there is a small set of objects of $X_{ét}$ which can be used to cover all other objects, and so a sheaf is uniquely determined by the values it takes on a small subcategory of $X_{ét}$.  Indeed, since an étale map is locally of finite presentation, it suffices to consider affine schemes which are finitely presented étale covers of affine open subsets of $X$, and there is an (essentially) small set of these.

Comment: What about the big étale site? Is there a similar trick that we can do? For examples, do affine f.p. schemes suffice?

Comment: My understanding is that there is no similar trick for the big étale site.  To work rigorously with big étale sheaves in ZFC you must restrict the big étale site to a small subcategory which is large enough for whatever particular application you are doing at the moment.  See for instance Definition 33.4.6 and the following material on the [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0214).

Comment: Then I have a question. In her work _Topos annelés et schemas relatifs_, Hakim uses a site,say $S_1$, which has as objects finitely presented affine schemes over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$, as morphisms étale morphisms, and as topology the étale topology. Then she proves things about the topos of sheaves of this site. It is common to say that "Hakim proved the classifying property for the étale topos". But why? If $S_1$ does not present the big étale topos, something is missing. (And of course it does not present the little étale topos, since we never require schemes to be étale over $X$.)

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond my expertise.

Comment: Could you give a reference for your answer that gives complete proves? Thank you.