# Why aren't sheaf categories locally small?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, functors, representable-functor

Given a scheme $S$ and reasonable topology, such as Zariski, étale, or fppf, is the category of sheaves ${Sh}(({Sch}/S)_{top})$ locally small? Or, if you like to assume that a category must be locally small, are usual sheaf "categories" actually categories at all?

The category $({Sch}/S)$ is not small, so the category of presheaves ${Fun}(({Sch}/S)^{opp},({Sets}))$ is not locally small. In fact this is a sheaf category, using the indiscrete topology (only $\mathrm{id}_X$ is a cover). As pointed out in the comments, the category of sheaves in the the discrete topology (everything, including $\varnothing \to X$, is a cover) is not only locally small, but small. So the answer certainly depends on topology, but it feels like it should be the same between Zariski, étale, and fppf topologies.

At this point I expect a negative answer, but I am still not sure exactly why. Is the Freyd–Street construction of a functor $T$, with endomorphisms indexed by equivalence classes of objects in $(Sch/S)$, an fppf (étale, Zariski) sheaf? $T$ takes an object $X$ to the set of split quotient objects $\pi: X \to Q$, plus a distinct element called $0$:
$$TX = \{\text{split quotient objects } \pi:X \to Q\} \amalg \{0\}$$
For a morphism $f: X \to Y$, the function $Tf: TY \to TX$ assigns a quotient object $\pi: Y \to Q$ to the morphism $\pi f: X \to Q$ if $\pi f$ is a split quotient object of $X$, and $0$ if not.

This process of adding a single element to some naturally defined set seems somehow like it should break sheafiness for topologies finer than Zariski. Is that the case? If so, is there a simple counterexample to local smallness of $Sh((Sch/S)_{Zar})$?

This question is relevant: [Is the étale site a small category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982210/is-the-%C3%A9tale-site-a-small-category?rq=1) However, no one there addresses my question directly, and for my purposes I am not interested in small sites.

Comment: In general, one should only expect the category of sheaves on a site S to be locally small if S itself is small. However, there are some exceptions - if the topology is the trivial topology (where the empty set is a cover for all objects), then the category will be locally small. I'm not sure if there's a nice way to categorise these exceptions.

Comment: This is surprising to me, considering I know some people who consider categories to be necessarily locally small, and also refer to sheaves as living inside categories. But people have certainly been wrong before

Comment: From what I've read, people often completely sidestep these issues by positing Grothendieck universes (which means that you're working in a theory much stronger than ZFC). Quoting ncatlab: "The astute reader will have noticed that we consider the category of all functors $CRing \to Set$ – which is not a locally small category. Nor is the category of sheaves on the site $CRing^{op}$ with its Zariski topology actually a Grothendieck topos."

Comment: I think people usually sidestep it by igoring it. It rarely if ever matters, anyway.

Comment: My motivating interest has to do with limit preservation, so there's definitely some importance of the concepts "big" and "small." But quite likely you're right that it doesn't matter

Comment: It turns out that for my question, it doesn't matter whether the categories are locally small. I was trying to use existence of a left adjoint to prove a limit is preserved, but there is no need for a local smallness assumption here (the proof of limit preservation can be applied in a very ad hoc way). But I'm still interested to know: if we know that these categories aren't locally small, how do we know it?

Comment: There is probably some explicit clever counterexample. But we could also say that, in practice, the collection of morphisms between two sheaves of interest is usually (essentially) small, because sheaves of interest are usually colimits of small diagrams of representable sheaves. That takes care of size issues but there is still a complexity issue because a natural transformation of functors with large domain is a large amount of data, so even a singleton consisting of such a natural transformation is, strictly speaking, not small.

Comment: If I understand correctly, one does not consider the category of all sheaves over these sites, but "small" sheaves in the sense that it is left Kan extended from the full subcategory $\operatorname{Sch}_\kappa/S$ where $\kappa\gg|S|$ is a cutoff cardinal. In this case, the category of sheaves is, by definition, locally small. For example, you could look at §8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.07343.pdf